# Разделение строки на отдельные части

Tags: c++, строки

Недавно писал программу и столкнулся с одной проблемой.

Проблема заключалась в строке:

```
string s = "7@";
```

Так вот в чем же сама проблема:

"7" - это номер ключа в моей программе, а "@" - это часть ключа (вид). В одной функции мне надо узнать именно этот вид ключа(без цифры).

Как это сделать? 
Разделить эту строку на "7" и "@" отдельно?

Comment: А нельзя просто сделать `s[1]`?

Comment: Если результат нужен в виде строки, используйте метод [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). `std::string s1 = s.substr(0, 1); std::string s2 = s.substr(1, 1);`

Comment: @acade, для чего, простите, использовать подстроки, если проще воспользоваться оператором []? Автору явно нужна не подстрока (хоть и из одного символа), а человек, который в теории может потом прочесть этот код, будет введен в ступор.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так как я могу использовать [] если у меня одна строка а не масив

Comment: @leocoolguy0, string - это, по сути, массив символов, получить доступ к элементам можно точно так же, как и у массива - через [] или через, например, string::at.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, существуют ситуации, когда нужна имеено строка. автор увидит все возможные варианты и выберет подходящее решение для его задачи. + если номер ключа может быть не одноразрядным? тогда `operator[]` и вовсе не подойтет

Comment: @acade, справедливый аргумент, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем понятно, зачем в данном случае вообще разделять строку. Строка здесь - некий "контейнер", зачем же нам тогда нарушать его целостность, если мы всего лишь хотим прочитать один из его элементов?

Так что вопрос здесь - "Как получить значение символа строки, зная его индекс?".

---

[Способов получить значение символа в строке у нас много:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**1. operator[]**

Наверное, самый привычный для новичков способ из представленных - с его помощью можно получить доступ к элементам массива. Применение абсолютно идентичное:

```
    std::string str = "7@";
    std::cout << str[1];
```

**2. std::string::at(size_t)**

Очень похожий на предыдущий оператор метод, принимает все тот же индекс, но при этом проверяет, не вышел ли этот индекс за пределы массива. Применение:

```
    std::string str = "7@";
    std::cout << str.at(1);
```

**3. std::string::back()**

В вопросе сказано, что нужный элемент находится на 2м месте, а размер строки - 2, значит, нужный элемент является последним в строке. У std::string есть метод обращения к первому и последнему элементу - front и back, в данном случае нам, очевидно, нужен std::string::back:

```
    std::string str = "7@";
    std::cout << str.back();
```

---

**Почему *не* стоит использовать std::string::substr(...), как указали в комментариях**

Все просто, substr(...) возвращает std::string, пускай даже от одного элемента, это все равно строка, а не символ.

Представим ситуацию, у нас есть функция, которая принимает символ:

```
void foobar(char) {...}
```

Использование substr не будет работать - нам нужен char, а не string. Для данного вопроса можно, конечно, решить эту проблему:

```
std::string str = "7@";
foobar(str.substr(1, 1)[0]); // замечательно
foobar(str.substr(1, 1).at(0)); // еще лучше
```

Думаю, тут и без объяснений все ясно :)

Поэтому не стоит изобретать велосипед, если нам нужно получить символ - используем методы строки для получения символа, а не подстроки.

Answer (score 1):

Получить из строки цифры и буквы:

```
string s("2algo34rithm5"), numbers, letters;
size_t pos = stable_partition(s.begin(), s.end(),
                       [](char c) { return isdigit(c); }) - s.begin();
numbers = s.substr(0, pos);  //все цифры
letters = s.substr(pos);    //все буквы
```